# List of all authors avatars

Tags: author, avatar, author-template, list-authors

I'm looking for a way to retrieve all authors with their avatar.

I know there is a way to get an authors avatar but I want to get all avatars of all the authors :)

```
echo get_avatar(get_the_author_meta('ID'), '160');
```

I tried to combine this command with `wp_list_authors()` but didn't find a way.

How can I retrieve a list of all authors with their avatars?

Thank you!

Comment: Keep in mind that authors are just users that have posts, behind the scenes `wp_list_authors` just uses the user API functions, and so can you, `get_the_author_meta` is just a wrapper around `get_user_meta( $post->post_author, 'ID'...`

Comment: Use wp_list_authors() and put them into an array then loop through the array using get_avatar() for each.

Comment: I don't believe `wp_list_authors` is the solution, that function returns a HTML/plaintext string rather than an array of users

Answer (score 0):

I would loop through an array with the authors and then get their avatar and save them in a different array. You can use `get_users()` to get the users and you already know how to get their avatar.

You can get users using `get_users()` by giving it an array with arguments to specify what you need. You can see the available arguments to pass in [the documentation for get_users()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_users/). This will return an array with users to loop through.

Comment: Can you explain retrieving a list of authors? The OP mentioned `wp_list_authors` but hadn't figured out how to use it

Comment: You should read the docs on this function, they are pretty clear. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_authors/ If you still have questions after scanning this, I'll be happy to answer them.

Comment: Oh I know how to use it :) But try to make your answers self contained, the OP may be missing a vital piece of information that's obvious to all of us, or be new too PHP. There's no no need to write out a copy paste solution though

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry @Tom, I didn't notice you were giving me feedback haha. I'll update my answer, thanks!

Comment: btw looking at the documentation suggests that `wp_list_authors` returns a string, not an array of users that can be looped with. Perhaps `get_users` may prove more useful

Comment: @TomJNowell Good catch, hadn't noticed that. Updated the answer, thanks!